# UserName and UserPassword Verification function

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

i'm afraid to use User forms data to query the database for user login, since the company has only 20 employees, I'm thinking of this function but I'm no sure if this still a easy code to crack for any no so good hacker user

```
Private Function VerifyCredentials(ByVal User As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean


    Dim verification As Boolean = False
    Dim _conString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
("YounnectionString").ConnectionString

    'Initialize connections variables
    Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(_conString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    cnn.Open()

    'No data from the form are used on the SQL Server
    cmd.CommandText = "Select UserName, UserPassword from tblUsers;"

    Dim cmdReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    'compare the data from the server with the data from the form, it so not matter what the user send from the form
    While cmdReader.Read()
        If Trim(User) = Trim(cmdReader("UserName")) 
        AndAlso Trim(Password) = Trim(cmdReader("UserPassword")) Then
            verification = True
        End If
    End While
    ' this method may result on performance problems if your tblUsers is too big, 
 'afther all it is the entrance and most of the companies 
 'just has several hundred users
    cmdReader.Close()
    cmd.CommandText = ""
    cnn.Close()

    Return verification

End Function
```

Please some one check this code and give me better solution, this company was hack ones and the developer was fired. I'm dont know about security but they want a solution while hire a expert. thanks

Comment: Pls delete your code and implement ASP. NET identity solution. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just storing plain text password. Once your database is compromised, you do not have time to notify users.

You need to store hashed password with salt. Although, it can still be cracked (it takes times) but you still have sometime to notify users to change the password.

For ASP.Net, the easiest way will be to use

1. [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) or
2. [ASP.NET Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that

Answer (score 0):

Let the database filter for you.
Change the query to

```
"Select UserName, UserPassword from tblUsers
WHERE UserName = " & Trim(User) & " AND UserPassword = " & Trim(Password)
```

And then, if there is some result the authentication is correct, and if there's no result, obviusly you have to return false, so simply do

```
Return cmdReader.Read()
```

Comment: this code was this way and that's why (I guess) get hack because it is sending the user form data to the query.. thanks any way Nahuel

Comment: @user295454 ***Do not use this code. It'll lead you to [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead, you want to use [parameterized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter).***

Comment: Thanks Win for the advise

Answer (score -1):

Use it

Introducing ASP.NET Identity – A membership system for ASP.NET applications

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx

Comment: I mess clicking the number here, this  -1 for clark Kent do not meant to be.. dont know how to fix it, Clark and Win actually answer good

Comment: @user295454 Pls click up arrow again. :)